# Google Authentication In Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-authentication

I am trying to authenticate a user in a Xamarin Forms app. I believe it has to be done differently for each platform, so I am using a function in MainActivity to authenticate when the app starts. I used the Google .NET documentation on their site but I am getting some errors.

I've directly copied the Google code and I get the credentials.json through an embedded resource. The problem occurs when I try to setup the credential with GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync. In the google code, the credPath is set to token.json. I get an error that I don't have permission for this. I then tried to use Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory and I now get multiple errors. I cannot see the individual errors, only System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.

```
UserCredential credential;
var assembly = typeof(MainActivity).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
using (var stream = 
assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Briefing.Droid.credentials.json"))
{
   // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
   // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
   string credPath = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path, "token.json");
   credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
   GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
   Scopes,
    "user",
    CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
    Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
 }
```

I expected a window to open that allowed the user to login with their google account. I get System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.

Comment: You can refer to this link.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/oauth#processing-the-redirect-url, And this is code of this demo.https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WebServices/OAuthNativeFlow/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Xamarin Auth. Refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/oauth

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the idea that everything has to be done in Native code? Authenticating with Social networks is very common scenario and there are already binded libraries for most of them.
This one is for Google Authentication 
https://causerexception.com/2017/12/03/google-native-login-with-xamarin-forms/

Comment: I've tried that link and got errors. The reason I thought it needs to be platform specific is that it uses CustomTabs to display the login, and an iOS equivalent. I eventually got it to work for android through this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/oauth